# Enabling mod_spdy with mod_proxy_ajp to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spdy, mod-proxy-ajp

I am using `mod_proxy_ajp` to **Tomcat**.

If I enable `mod_spdy`...

- Will this mean that connections over the proxy will be **SPDY** enabled?